# Show XML files in a DataGridView

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview

I'm creating an application that stores an XML file for every order in a company. I do not know much about VB.NET yet and would like to know how I could show the rows of each XML file inside the folder in a DataGridView. (Each XML file has only one line, and the schema is created directly by VB using XMLWriteSchema).
Here's the code i'm using for XML writing:

```
Dim DT As New DataTable
DT.TableName = "Ordini"
DT.Columns.Add("ID ordine")
DT.Columns.Add("Descrizione")
DT.Columns.Add("Prezzo")
DT.Columns.Add("Compratore")
DT.Columns.Add("Q.tà")
DT.Columns.Add("Vettore")
DT.Columns.Add("Data/ora")
DT.Rows.Add(txtOrderID.Text, txtDescription.Text, txtPrice.Text, txtCustomer.Text, txtQuantity.Text, cboVector.selectedValue, Datepicker.Value)
DT.WriteXml(Application.StartupPath & "\orders\order_" + txtOrderID.Text + ".xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
```

How do i load each XML file row in a DataGridView? Thanks!

Comment: That code has nothing to do with loading or reading an XML file. Have you tried anything?  Research anything?  Read [ask] and take the [tour] - those elements are required here.

Comment: The DGV has a property DataSource.  So you can make the DataSource the DT : datagridview1.DataSource = DT

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to serialize a DataTable to create the XML using the DataTable's [WriteXml method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx) and then deserialize it back to a DataTable using the DataTable's [ReadXml method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx). By doing that, you can then bind the DataTable to the DataGridView.

You're already utilizing the WriteXml method, now simply implement the ReadXml method and bind the DataGridView:

```
'Create a new instance of the DataTable and read the serialized data
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
dt.ReadXml("my path here.xml")

'Bind the DataGridView to the DataTable
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```